# Code resource GET request issues

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, cloudpage

I have a set of three pages that I developed in a development instance; HTML page, a JS code resource responsible for GET requests and a JS code resource responsible for POST requests.

In the development instance everything works perfect.

Moved it into clients instance:
In Firefox, everything works.

In Chrome and Safari my GET requests all fail with 500 errors, but by error handling turns around and does a post to log the error successfully.

Both are on the same domain so not a CORS issue, I have the `Access control allow`  headers on the code resource.

I feel like the fact that it works in Firefox rules out syntax errors on the get page...

Comment: I’ve dug into the response headers a bit more, in the instances it’s failing the response headers are coming through as `text/html` rather than `application/JSON` like in the ones that succeed. I’ve tried to set the content type headers but nothing seems to stick...

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR - just because code works in one browser and not the others does not mean you don’t have syntax errors.

I had 3 lines of code that were duplicate and looking for the wrong cookie for a lookup.

In Chrome and Safari it threw the exception, in FireFox it didn’t.